# index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, arrays

I am filling two arrays, `field_in_k_space_REAL` and `field_in_k_space_IMAGINARY`, with values extracted from a Gaussian distribution, paying attention to respect the symmetry to get a real field when I inverse-transform the arrays. Here is the code:

```
field_in_k_space_REAL = zeros(n, float)
field_in_k_space_IMAGINARY = zeros(n, float)

field_in_k_space_REAL[0] = 0.0

for i in range(1, int(n/2+1)):
    field_in_k_space_REAL[i] = np.random.normal(mu, math.sqrt((1/2)*math.exp(-(2*math.pi*i*sigma/L)*(2*math.pi*i*sigma/L))))

x = range(int(n/2+1), int(n))
y = range(1, int(n/2))
zipped = zip(x, y)

for j, j2 in zipped:
    field_in_k_space_REAL[j] = field_in_k_space_REAL[j-2*j2]

field_in_k_space_IMAGINARY[0] = 0.0

for i in range(1, int(n/2)):
    field_in_k_space_IMAGINARY[i] = np.random.normal(mu, math.sqrt((1/2)*math.exp(-(2*math.pi*i*sigma/L)*(2*math.pi*i*sigma/L))))

field_in_k_space_IMAGINARY[n/2] = 0.0

for j, j2 in zipped:
    field_in_k_space_IMAGINARY[j] = - field_in_k_space_IMAGINARY[j-2*j2]

print 'field_k', field_in_k_space_REAL
```

But I keep having the following error:

```
 field_in_k_space_REAL[0] = 0.0
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Can someone explain why and how to fix it?

Comment: What is the value of `n`?

Comment: @Cyber n = 32, but I can change it

Comment: With a value of `n = 32` I am unable to reproduce the error that you showed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My guess is that the array `field_in_k_space_REAL` is actually of length 0, most likely because you set `n = 0` further up in your code (do you use `n` in a loop maybe?). I can reproduce the error when I directly initialize an array of length 0.

Answer (score 0):

in fact, you'd better use:

```
field_in_k_space_REAL.loc[index] = 0.0
```

instead of:

```
field_in_k_space_REAL[index] = 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because of NAN value in your close column use **np.isfinite**.
For example :

```
btt_ohlc[np.isfinite(btt_ohlc['Close'])]
```