# Error loading data into temporary numpy array: "IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0"

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have the following code. I am retrieving the prediction results of one image and storing it in a `tmp` numpy array.

```
print(predictions.shape) # 14,14,512
tmp=np.zeros((0, 14, 14, 512))
for i in range(0, 1):
   tmp[i,:,:]=predictions[i,:]
```

Error received running the above code.

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `numpy.zeros()` with a tuple starting with zero results in the array being empty.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> tmp = np.zeros((0, 14, 14, 512))
>>> tmp
array([], shape=(0, 14, 14, 512), dtype=float64)
```

To initialize `tmp` with zeros, you could do:

```
>>> tmp = np.zeros((14, 14, 512))
>>> tmp
array([[[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]],
...
```

### Complete example

```
import numpy as np

predictions = np.random.randint(9, size=(14 * 14 * 512)).reshape((14, 14, 512))
print(f"shape of predictions: {predictions.shape}")
tmp = np.zeros((14, 14, 512))

tmp[0,:,:] = predictions[0,:]
print(f"shape of tmp: {tmp.shape}")
print(f"tmp data:\n{tmp}")
```

#### Output

```
shape of predictions: (14, 14, 512)
shape of tmp: (14, 14, 512)
tmp data:
[[[0. 0. 8. ... 6. 8. 1.]
  [8. 6. 0. ... 4. 5. 3.]
  [7. 6. 2. ... 6. 7. 6.]
  ...
  [4. 2. 4. ... 1. 5. 8.]
  [4. 3. 8. ... 0. 5. 0.]
  [4. 5. 3. ... 0. 0. 1.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  ...
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]

 ...
```

## See also

[**What does 'index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0' mean?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41492288/1164465)

Comment: thanks alot , your help is highly appreciated @Christopher